# how to sort a collection by datetime in c#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a List that I need to sort by DateTime, the class MyStuff looks like:

```
public class MyStuff
{
   public int Type {get;set;}
   public int Key {get;set;}
   public DateTime Created {get;set;}
}
```

I need to be able to sort the collection List by the Created (DateTime) field.

Answer (score 135):

You seem to be working with a `List<T>` object, in which case the most efficient (and a simple) method would be the following:

```
myList.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.Created, y.Created));
```

This uses the overload of the [List.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method than takes a `Comparison<T>` delegate (and thus lambda expression).

You can of course use the LINQ `OrderBy` extension method, but I don't think this offers any advantages, and can be significantly slower, depending on your situation.

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Created).ToList();
```

Comment: I would not worry about "performance" here. Although props for pointing out no LINQ/sort-by needed.

Comment: The key difference between the two methods is that `List<T>.Sort` sorts the existing list, while `OrderBy` returns a new `IEnumerable<T>` and leaves the list alone. That's either an advantage if you want to keep the original list, or a performance hit if you don't.

Comment: @stevemegson: This is very true. However, in-place sorts are typically more common.

Comment: Also very true. Of course under the hood they're both really in-place sorts, you just get to choose which place. OrderBy more or less calls Array.Sort(myList.ToArray()), while myList.Sort calls Array.Sort directly on the List's internal array. More or less.

Comment: @stevemegson: Yeah... I would be curious to see how a list clone & List.Sort compares to OrderBy, actually. Probably very similar.

Comment: Old post, I know, but it might be useful if someone were to include information and/or references showing how DateTime structs are sorted by default.  That is, will an ascending sort place newer dates first or last?  And how will time zones play into it?

Comment: How can you do OrderByDescending using this your Sort suggestion?

Comment: @batmaci To order by descending, just switch the position of the x and y in Compare. 

`myList.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(y.Created, x.Created));`

Answer (score 11):

```
var query = 
    from m in mystuffcollection
    orderby m.Created ascending
    select m;
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for a way to sort the data on the basis of a nested property can use the sort function something like below:

```
MyList.Sort((x, y) => x.Datetime.CompareTo(y.Datetime));
```

Now the major differences between using OrderBy and Sort are performance and return value.

Sort basically sorts the existing `List<T>` whereas OrderBy returns a new `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `using System.Linq;` from entity framework, considering you are using .net core in your application. The Linq provides you both FilterBy and OrderBy methods, for custom FilterBy and OrderBy you need to override the methods in your class or Repository.

```
 override
 protected IQueryable<T> FilterBy(IQueryable<T> myProcess, string filterBy, string filterValue)
                {
                    var listFilter = filterBy.Split(',');
                    var listValues = filterValue.Split(',');

                    for (int index = 0; index < listFilter.Length; index++)
                    {
                        var filter = listFilter[index];
                        var value = listValues[index];

                        switch (filter)
                        {
                            case "type":
                                myProcess = myProcess.Where(c => c.Status.Nome.Contains(value));
                                break;
                            case "created":
                                  myProcess = myProcess.Where(c => c.Created - DateTime.Parse(value) >= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
                            default:
                               break;
                  }
                }
              }

    override
    protected IQueryable<T> OrderBy(IQueryable<T> myProcess, string attribute, string direction)
                {
                    switch (attribute)
                    {
                        case "type":
                            myProcess = (direction == "asc")
                                ? myProcess.OrderBy(c => c.Type)
                                : myProcess.OrderByDescending(c => c.Type);
                            return myProcess;
                        case "created":
                            myProcess = (direction == "asc")
                                ? myProcess.OrderBy(c => c.Created)
                                : myProcess.OrderByDescending(c => c.Created);
                    return myProcess;
                 }
                }
```

Comment: This would be better if you use `T` instead of `myStuff` and gave a calling example.

Comment: Yes, I agreed, in this way is more general than 'myStuff'. Thanks a lot!