# .net mvc3 sort list of objects by date variable

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of "BlogPost" each with a date variable.

Is there an easy way in .net mvc3 to sort the list based on their date or do I need to write my own sorting alogorithm by hand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to sort a collection by datetime in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618863/how-to-sort-a-collection-by-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a lot of assumptions since you gave very little information, just use Linq.

```
List<BlogPost> posts = GetBlogPosts();
posts.Sort(b => b.Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

> or do I need to write my own sorting alogorithm by hand?

NO!! we dont live in the stone age anymore...

you have provided no information in your question such as what is the data access mechanism Linq? using any ORM's like NHibernate? or entity? or linq2sql? or querying the db by opening a connection and then executing sql statements?

if you are using Linq then you can try

```
var _x = ( from x in DBContext.BlogPost
           orderby x.Date select x).ToList();
```

or

```
string myConnectionString = "connectionstring"; //you connectionstring goes here

SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select * from BlogPost order by Date", new SqlConnection(myConnectionString));
cmd.Connection.Open();
//some execute scalar stuff goes here i really dont remember 
cmd.Connection.Close();
```