# How do I emulate sort by 'date' (the column in explorer) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, date

In explorer, you can sort files by the following metadata fields

- date
- date created
- date modified
- date taken
- etc.

In C# I only have access to these

- `FileInfo.LastWriteTime`
- `FileInfo.CreationTime` and
- `FileInfo.LastAccessTime`

I'm not quite sure what the 'date' column actually is in explorer, for some files it is equal to date modified, but for others 'date' is older than 'date modified'.

How do I sort by 'date' in C#?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/147525/what-is-the-date-column-in-windows-7-explorer-it-matches-no-date-column-from

Comment: Enumerate the files in a directory. List each of those three FileInfo dates for each one. Compare to what you see in Explorer for the same files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618863/how-to-sort-a-collection-by-datetime-in-c-sharp

Comment: @David Thanks, that's exactly what I need!

Comment: @Andrew, I know how to sort a list. And to the downvoters, if I may, what is wrong with my question?

Comment: @SimonVerbeke, because question is poorly asked. It is very difficult to understand what do you want :) Now I understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Date' in Explorer is almost always the same as 'Date Modified', the exception being if a 'Date' is exposed via a files Extended Properties.

To read the Extended Properties of a file requires using some COM components exposed by Shell32 - there's no way to do this in pure C#. There's a general purpose to answer on how to read a files extended properties via Shell32 here: [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)