# How to order by lastModifiedDateTime or lastModifiedBy user displayName in Graph API?

Tags: azure, sorting, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to order documents by `lastModifiedDateTime` in Graph API.

But it says `The property Modified is not supported for OrderBy.`.

I use the following API since I need to use `folder-id`.

[image]

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/children?orderby=lastModifiedDateTime desc`.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/children?orderby=lastModifiedBy/user/displayName desc`.

But they didn't work at all.

Please let me know the correct use of Graph API.

Thank you.

Comment: I would create a class to hold values from the returned json and then a simple LINQ query can order the list by any property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this document: [Sorting collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/optional-query-parameters?view=odsp-graph-online#sorting-collections):

> Note that in OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Server 2016, the
> orderby query string only works with **name** and **url**.

Sharepoint online is actually OneDrive for Business.

So filtering by `lastModifiedDateTime` is not supported in this case. It is supported for OneDrive Personal.

You need to get the result first and then sort it in your code. For C# you can look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618863/how-to-sort-a-collection-by-datetime-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Thank you for your posting. Actually, I found that Graph API doesn't provide filtering by `lastModifiedDateTime`, but I didn't believe it. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: In case of filtering by `displayName`, is it the same as `lastModifiedDateTime`?

Comment: @hotcakedev Since we cannot filter with `lastModifiedDateTime`, I'm not sure if the results are the same:(

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @hotcakedev What I mean is that I'm not sure if we filter by `displayName`, the result will be the same as `lastModifiedDateTime` because I cannot verify it.

Comment: @hotcakedev Glad to know that:)

Comment: Can you answer to my another question? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293271/deleting-an-event-returns-success-but-not-worked-actually